# JQuery Listbox Weird error only in Chrome Browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I m out off idea about this.

it should be easy task, but Chrome made terrible.
I have 2 listbox Region and area. the idea is only show areas when region selected.
It's working fine in firefox but not in Chrome.
after trial and error i found that if listbox option reduced it's working but with many options it's not working ONLY in Chrome, another browser is fine.

please see script in paste bin. there's 2 list box version. the working version is commented.

http://pastebin.com/jt8JwFj4

Thank you

Comment: Would be good if you can put it into a fiddle to look at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: okay. here are the link
http://jsfiddle.net/HU5xv/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webkit browsers is has it's  objects kinda isolated from CSS styling. That means you're unable to do stuffs like .show(), .hide() and alike.

Expect some `.detach()` and `.append()` calls to work, or simply start using a template engine.

You called `.fadeIn()` in jsFiddle, assuming you want it hidden at the first place.

HTML:

```
<select id="fstarted-areas" style="display: none">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get hold of all options
    var areaOptions = $("#fstarted-areas option");

    $("#fstarted-region").change(function() {
        // Also with a multiple selection I assume you need to get ALL 
        // selected instead of the first one.
        var regs = $("#fstarted-region :selected").map(function(i, el) {
            return '.' + $(el).val();
        });

        regs = $.makeArray(regs);

        // Detach all options, chain the search option.
        regs = areaOptions.detach().filter(regs.join(', '));

        // Add options into selection, then show it.
        $("#fstarted-areas").append(regs).fadeIn(500);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Forgot the jQuery.fn.map() is returning a jQuery object, it should be converted to plain array with jQuery.makeArray() before using Array.prototype.join(). Also changed from .find() to .filter(). See my update on your jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/YudsE/6/

Comment: Thank you!.. it's working.
but little bugs the listbox option not show..
so i m adding `areaOptions.show();` after append.
Final working code: http://jsfiddle.net/YudsE/9/

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution for your problem check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YudsE/) out

javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function(){                
            $("#fstarted-region").change(function() {
                var reg = $("#fstarted-region :selected").val();
                if(reg==''){
                    $("#fstarted-areas").hide();
                }else{
                    $("#fstarted-areas").show();
                    $("#fstarted-areas option").hide();
                    $("#fstarted-areas option."+reg).show();
                }

            });

        });
```

css

```
 #fstarted-areas option {
display: none;
}

#fstarted-areas{
display: none;
}
#fstarted-areas option.always {
display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. 
but it's not working with many option in CHROME Browser
kindly please check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/YudsE/1/